# How to prove that the intersection of countably many open sets of reals is either at most countable or of cardinality continuum?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, descriptive-set-theory

I've learned that any Borel set in $\mathbb R^n$ is either countable or of cardinality continuum from Springer's [*Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory.*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-36219-3) I wonder if there exists some more elementary proofs for the specific case of $G_\delta$ sets in $\mathbb R$.

Below is my trying on this but got stuck.

Suppose $A=\cap_{i=0}^\infty V_i$, where each $V_i$ is open and for each $i\in\mathbb N$, $V_{i+1}\subseteq V_i$. If $A$ contains an interval, then its cardinality equals that of the continuum. Suppose that no interval is contained in $A$. Let $V_i=\cup_{j=0}^\infty J_{i,j}$, where $J_{i,j}$ are disjoint open intervals (and without losing generality we can assume that all with finite length), and for each $i>0, j\in\mathbb N$, there is a unique $J_{i-1,j_{i-1}}$ such that $J_{i,j}\subseteq J_{i-1,j_{i-1}}$. Hence $\forall a\in A$, $\{a\}=\cap_{i=0}^\infty J_{i,j_i}$ and the correspondence between $a$ and the sequence of naturals $\{j_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ is one-to-one. But I failed to find an one-to-one mapping from the set of all the possible sequences to a subset of $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I'd be surprised if what you're trying to do is possible. Note that every closed set is $G_\delta$ and the usual (only?) proof that closed sets satisfy CH goes via the Cantor--Bendixson Theorem. So I'd assume that a proof that $G_\delta$ sets satisfy $CH$ is at least equally hard. Also, I have some trouble understanding proof. Many sequences $(j_i)_{i<\omega}$ might give rise to empty sets, so there is not really much to say from there.

Comment: Your proof idea cannot work: Consider the set of irrational numbers $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. It is a $G_\delta$ set of size continuum that doesn't contain an interval.

Comment: Accidentally, I left this as an exercise in my logic course. Hopefully you are not my students.